# don't know why rails route to users/index instead of index_home_path after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After submit rails route to users/index instead of index_home_path.

Here are my code: 
controlller: http://pastebin.com/LA4Wj0d4
view: http://pastebin.com/VuEVDakn

I hope somebody can help me
Thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: thanks i have seen my mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested form elements, and the outermost form element is controlling the action.  Specifically, this element:

```
<form class="login-form" action="index.html" method="post">
```

defines the action as the index page.

Comment: tanks a lot! this is the answer